# About opacity in StreamPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am using StreamPlot3D to plot some background field lines, which are supposed to be gray and contain opacity. I used for example:

```
StreamPlot3D[{x^2/(y^2 + 3), y, z}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10,10}, {z, -10, 10}, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False,StreamPoints -> 20, StreamScale -> Full,StreamStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.3], Thickness[0.005]], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, StreamColorFunction -> None, PlotRange -> Full]
```

But the field lines contain strange dots. Can anyone help me to get rid of that?

[image]

Comment: works for me on V 13.3 using windows 10. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnkjD.png)  no **strange dots.** that I could see. It is always useful to say which version you are using and the OS. It could be something that was fixed.

Comment: Is this present already in Mathematica GUI or only when you export it (eg. in PDF)?

Comment: Thank you Nasser. I'm using M1 Mac. I tried to download v13.3, but it is not consistent with my MAC and I cannot open the file. I tried v13.2, but the problem exists...

Comment: Hi Domen, it already exists in Mathematica GUI.

Comment: I see the same artefacts (v13.3 on MacOS, Intel processor if that matters).  Fiddling around I found that if I re-execute the same command the drawing re-displays without the strange dots.  Further fiddling suggests that the size of the drawing also has an impact on the presence or absence of the dots, so perhaps a visualisation artefact in play. But strange.